# Increase Vscode's "Error and Warnings..." menu width, or make it wrap?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode my errors often get cut off from the "Errors and warnings" menu that appears when I press ⌘ + ALT + SHIFT.

[image]

Lots of my errors are much longer than the available space. How could I increase the width - or even better, make errors wrap.

EDIT 1 - Issue opened in Github: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/845

**EDIT 2 - [Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/845) is in VSCode [backlog milestone](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aopen+milestone%3ABacklog+%22Command+Prompt%22)**

Comment: if you are using a newer version of VS Code that instead has the Problems Panel instead of the error list, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/77242319/11107541.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a way to change this yourself. Hopefully they will wrap in the future, or expand when in focus.

Edit: More information. There doesn't appear to be anything in the preferences or in the extension API that suggests that users or developers have any control over changing this behavior at this time.