# How to word-wrap long messages in VSCode problem window?

Tags: visual-studio-code, word-wrap

In VS Code as of version 1.82.3, there is a shortcut for word-wrapping (e.g. Alt + 'Z' on Windows) in the editor window.

Is there something similar for longer compiler error messages in the problem window?

As an example, see my screenshot - the Editor window does wrap text, and the Problems window doesn't.

[image]

Comment: Add a screenshot and repro step so we can have a look.

Comment: note: this is a different question than [this similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33757338/11107541). that one is about an older version of VS Code where the Problems Panel did not exist yet, and there was a different view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was raised before in this issue ticket: [Display full text in Problems pane. #83235](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83235) with the request: "*Allow text in problems to word wrap or display full text on hover.*". Unfortunately the solution route taken was to just add the tooltip instead of enabling wrapping.

The mentioned workaround is to set `"workbench.list.horizontalScrolling": true` (in [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson)), though this will affect all lists and not just the one in the Problems Panel.

The other workaround is to mouseover the description to get the tooltip.

This command might also help (only to some degree- you are still at the mercy of where the newlines are in the original text): `Problems: Show message in multiple lines` (run in [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)).

I suppose you could try [raising the feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md) for wrapping again. If you do, please comment here with a link to your issue ticket, or edit the link into this answer post.

Note that a feature-request was attempted by the asker at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/195053, but it [failed to receive enough community support in the allotted window](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/195053#issuecomment-1859018313).

---

Fun extra readings that aren't directly related:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/33737 - For the inline problem widget, this is by design, to keep with text that relies on monospace spacing for positioning / aligning text in multiple lines.

Comment: Thx for the highly qualified answer. I'll consider raising a feature request, as you suggested.

Comment: The VS Code new issue number is 195053, here is the link:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/195053

Comment: The issue has been now reopened and is ready for upvoting. The community has 60 days to upvote the issue. If it receives 20 upvotes, they will move it to the backlog.